# Best way to obtain prefix and last part of url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a group route like this

**PHP LARAVEL 9**

```
/**
 * ACCOMODATIONS
 */
Route::controller(AccomodationsController::class)->group(function () {

        Route::prefix('accomodations')->group(function () {

            Route::GET('/', 'index');

            Route::GET('/italy', 'index');
    
            Route::GET('/greece', 'index');

        });

});
```

In the controller side I want to obtain the accomodations part and the italy greece part without slashes. I'm doing like this

**PHP LARAVEL 9**

```
class AccomodationsController extends Controller
{

    public function index(request $request){

        $listType = [
            'type' => trim($request->route()->getPrefix(), '/'),
            'route' => request()->segment(count(request()->segments()))
        ];

     dd($listType);
    
    );
}

/*
http://example.com/accomodations outputs
array [
  "type" => "accomodations"
  "route" => ""
]
/*

/*
http://example.com/accomodations/italy outputs
array [
  "type" => "accomodations"
  "route" => "italy"
]
*/

/*
http://example.com/accomodations/greece outputs
array [
  "type" => "accomodations"
  "route" => "greece"
]
*/
```

This works but the way I'm manipulating the request in $listType seems a little bloated to me, is there a cleaner way in laravel?

Comment: why not writing this line `'route' => request()->segment(count(request()->segments()))`
as 
`'route' =>  end($request()->segments)`

Comment: Why not define route as ```Route::GET('/{country?}', 'index');``` and then in your controller ```public function index(request $request, $country){...}```

Comment: how can I manage fixed parameterized routes in this way on my web.php side? I want that something different from italy or greece will give me error or 404

Comment: you can use route with parameter `where` & `whereIn` if required [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi oooh now is perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [parameterized route](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters) for same method.

**Routes**

```
Route::controller(AccomodationsController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('accomodations')->group(function () {
        Route::GET('/{destination}', 'index');
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request, $destination){
    $listType = [
        'type' => trim($request->route()->getPrefix(), '/'),
        'route' => $destination
    ];
    dd($listType);
);
```

If your destination is optional you can use [optional parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)

**Edit 1:**

Route with Optional Parameter

```
Route::controller(AccomodationsController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('accomodations')->group(function () {
        Route::GET('/{destination?}', 'index');
    });
});
```

Controller with Optional parameter

```
public function index(Request $request, $destination=''){
    $listType = [
        'type' => trim($request->route()->getPrefix(), '/'),
        'route' => $destination
    ];
    dd($listType);
);
```

you can assign any value (null, string, int, etc.) to the destination variable just like the default function argument in PHP.

Comment: ok but how can I handle the http://example.com/accomodations output? if I put the ? after {destination} to make it optional, how can I specify a default value using this group schema? Without default value, Laravel will throw an error too few arguments.

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Comment: thank you! I feel stupid, I'm accepting your answer